# SonarQube ignoring disabled stylecop rules

Tags: c#, configuration, sonarqube, static-analysis, stylecop

I am using SonarQube 5.0 on Windows 7 with the C# plugin 3.3, Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects 1.2 and Stylecop plugin 1.1 installed to analyse my C# solution.

I have disabled a number of stylecop rules inside SonarQube (mostly relating to file headers and copyright notices) but even after restarting the SonarQube server and executing a fresh analysis, issues are being created for the disabled rules.

I have only one quality profile, and the rules are disabled for it.

**sonar.properties**

```
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters.
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=[REDACTED]
sonar.jdbc.password=[REDACTED]

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://[REDACTED]/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2005/2008
# Only the distributed jTDS driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor


#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxActive=50

# The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the
# pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
#sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
#sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000

#sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
#sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
# sonar.web.host=[REDACTED]


# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
# sonar.web.port=9000

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=9000

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file. 
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# Access logs are generated in the file logs/access.log. This file is rolled over when it's 5Mb.
# An archive of 3 files is kept in the same directory.
# Access logs are enabled by default.
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=
#http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of information displayed in the logs: NONE (default), BASIC (functional information)
# and FULL (functional and technical details)
#sonar.log.profilingLevel=NONE

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
#sonar.path.logs=logs


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
#sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
#sonar.web.dev=false

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
#sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Uncomment to enable the Elasticsearch HTTP connector, so that ES can be directly requested through
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
#sonar.search.httpPort=9010
```

**sonar-project.properties**

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=[REDACTED]:latest
sonar.projectName=[REDACTED] Latest
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path to the parent source code directory.
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing 
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=[REDACTED]/

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

**StyleCop-settings.StyleCop**

The file was too long to post here, so I've included it in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/Jb718AyW

It is from one of the .sonar directories for an assembly for which I have confirmed SonarQube is erroneously detecting disabled rules.

Comment: All your rules seem to be `Enabled=True` in the file you posted.

Comment: It appears that SonarQube only includes enabled rules in the stylecop file and omits disabled rules entirely. As far as I can tell none of the stylecop rules in the file I provided are any that I have disabled. Additionally, a second clean run of SonarQube has correctly removed these errors, leading me to believe that SonarQube is caching issues in some way. However, since I cannot prove it either way any more (as the issues have disappeared), I have voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of an issue caching bug in SonarQube 5.0 indeed, where the actual analysis was all good (so the generated files are all using the up-to-date data), but old issues were still being displayed in the SonarQube interface.

These "ghost" issues would not move together with new edits made to the file.

This issue is supposed to be fixed in 5.1, please upgrade your SonarQube server.

Comment: Short of an upgrade, stop your server, delete the "data/es" directory, and restart. The bug is in the Elastic Search cache.